# is tensor2tensor/avg_checkpoints script wrong

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor2tensor

I am training two sub-models in parallel, and want to average them after both of them are finished.

The model is implemented out of tensor2tensor (but still use tensorflow). Part of the definition is like this:

```
    def build_model(self):
        layer_sizes = [n,n,n]
        kernel_sizes = [n,n,n]
        tf.reset_default_graph()
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        with self.graph.as_default():
            self.num_classes = num_classes
            # placeholder for parameter
            self.learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="learning_rate")
            self.dropout_keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="dropout_keep_prob")
            self.phase = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name="phase")
            # Placeholders for regular data
            self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, input_feature_dim], name="input_x")
            self.input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes], name="input_y")
            h = self.input_x
            ......[remaining codes]
```

I save it following:

```
    def save_model(sess, output):
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        save_path = saver.save(sess, os.path.join(output, 'model'))
```

When I load it, I use:

```
    def load_model(self, sess, input_dir, logger):
        if logger is not None:
            logger.info("Start loading graph ...")
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(input_dir, 'model.meta'))
        saver.restore(sess, os.path.join(input_dir, 'model'))
        self.graph = sess.graph
        self.input_x = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("input_x:0")
        self.input_y = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("input_y:0")
        self.num_classes = self.input_y.shape[1]
        self.learning_rate = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("learning_rate:0")
        self.dropout_keep_prob = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("dropout_keep_prob:0")
        self.phase = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("phase:0")
        self.loss = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("loss:0")
        self.optimizer = self.graph.get_operation_by_name("optimizer")
        self.accuracy = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("accuracy/accuracy:0")
```

I use the avg_checkpoint to average two sub-models:

```
python utils/avg_checkpoints.py
  --checkpoints path/to/checkpoint1,path/to/checkpoint2
  --num_last_checkpoints 2
  --output_path where/to/save/the/output
```

But I find problems when I check the avg_checkpoints code further:

```
    for checkpoint in checkpoints:
        reader = tf.train.load_checkpoint(checkpoint)
        for name in var_values:
            tensor = reader.get_tensor(name)
            var_dtypes[name] = tensor.dtype
            var_values[name] += tensor
        tf.logging.info("Read from checkpoint %s", checkpoint)
    for name in var_values:  # Average.
        var_values[name] /= len(checkpoints)

    with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        tf_vars = [
            tf.get_variable(v, shape=var_values[v].shape, dtype=var_dtypes[v])
            for v in var_values
        ]
    placeholders = [tf.placeholder(v.dtype, shape=v.shape) for v in tf_vars]
    assign_ops = [tf.assign(v, p) for (v, p) in zip(tf_vars, placeholders)]
    global_step = tf.Variable(
        0, name="global_step", trainable=False, dtype=tf.int64)
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())

    # Build a model consisting only of variables, set them to the average values.
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        for p, assign_op, (name, value) in zip(placeholders, assign_ops,
                                               six.iteritems(var_values)):
            sess.run(assign_op, {p: value})
        # Use the built saver to save the averaged checkpoint.
        saver.save(sess, FLAGS.output_path, global_step=global_step)
```

It only save the variables, not all tensors. E.G. when I load it using the above load_model function, it cannot have "input_x:0" tensor. Is this script wrong, or I should modify it based on my use?

I am using TF r1.13. Thanks!